# Is the Oil Pollution Act of 1990 included in the United States Code? Why can't I find §4201?

Tags: united-states, corporate-law

There are numerous texts stating that there was a Section 4201 of the Oil Pollution Act of 1990 in 2010. There are also numerous texts stating that OPA 90 §4201 was amended into the United States Code. So, why can't I find it on the GPO.gov website or the Cornell Law website? Title 33 stops at §3857.

Why isn't there a §4201 of Title 33 on [GPO.gov](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/USCODE-2010-title33/html/USCODE-2010-title33-chap40.htm) and/or where can I find §4201 of OPA 90?

Or am I wrong? Is OPA 90 not part of U.S. Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A particular section of a law passed by Congress will not necessarily translate into a section of the US code with the same number.

I looked up the [text](https://www.congress.gov/bill/101st-congress/house-bill/1465/text) of the bill and searched for 4201.  I found this:

> SEC. 4201. FEDERAL REMOVAL AUTHORITY.
>     (a) IN GENERAL- Subsection (c) of section 311 of the Federal Water Pollution Control Act (33 U.S.C. 1321(c)) is amended to read as follows:

And if you look at [33 USC 1321](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/33/1321)(c) (not to be confused with 33 USC 1321c) you'll find the law there in the statutes.